# RxJava . flatMap returning SingleList instead List<Object>

Tags: java, observable, rx-java, rx-android, flatmap

I have this chunk of code. I am trying to get JSONObjects from JSONArray and then turn it to List but getting singlelist instead of what i needed. Maybe i misunderstood something?(I'm new to rxJava)

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> client.newCall(request).execute())
            .map(resp -> Objects.requireNonNull(resp.body()).string())
            .map(JSONArray::new)
            .map(jsonArray -> {
                JSONObject[] jsonArr = new JSONObject[jsonArray.length()];
                for(int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    jsonArr[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                }
                return jsonArr;
            })
            .flatMap(Observable::fromArray).map(jsonObject -> {
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        String capital = jsonObject.getString("capital");
        Country country = new Country(name, capital);
        return country;
    }).toList()
            .map(// List<Country ->  -> etc. doing )
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using Gson?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- No, but i thought standart JSON would be enough. I'm learning rx java so i'ts more about learning  rx concepts

Comment: Where do you get that "singlelist"?